# Use of a matrix in a homogeneous system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

How to prove that "Every homogeneous system has at least one solution, known as the zero (or trivial) solution, which is obtained by assigning the value of zero to each of the variables. **If the system has a non-singular matrix ($\det(A) ≠ 0$) then it is also the only solution. If the system has a singular matrix then there is a solution set with an infinite number of solutions.**"?

I was thinking about use Cramer theorem and show that, when we have a set of $N\times N$ system, the denominator is the determinant of the coefficient Matrix, that is, our A matrix, so it can not vanish. But maybe this is just a particular case that can not be used as a generalization to prove, since we need, as i said, a $N\times N$ system, while $AX = O$ need just the number of columns of A be equal to number of lines of $X$.

What do you think?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222240/proving-that-a-square-matrix-whose-kernel-is-0-is-invertible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\det(A) \ne 0$ then by Cramer's rule, $A$ is invertible. That is, there is matrix $A^{-1}$ such that $AA^{-1} = A^{-1}A = I$, the identity matrix. So if $A\mathbf x = \mathbf 0$, then
$$A^{-1}A\mathbf x = A^{-1}\mathbf 0 = \mathbf 0$$
but also $$A^{-1}A\mathbf x = I\mathbf x = \mathbf x$$
Therefore $\mathbf x = \mathbf 0$. I.e., $\mathbf 0$ is the only solution to the system.

On the other hand, if $\det(A) = 0$, then $A$ is not invertible. By the Rank-Nullity theorem, this means that the null space of $A$ is not zero. I.e., there is some $\mathbf x \ne \mathbf 0$ such that $A\mathbf x = 0$, which provides one non-zero solution $\mathbf x$ to the system. But then for any scalar $m$, $$A(m\mathbf x) = mA\mathbf x = m\mathbf 0 = \mathbf 0$$
Since there are infinitely many scalars, and $m\mathbf x = n\mathbf x$ only when $m = n$, there are infinitely many solutions.